# Which part on the circuit board has the software or firmware?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, firmware, vfd, drive

I am having difficulty to locate which part holds the firmware or software to make the board function properly. The board is used as a control for a 375 kW drive. I replaced the board with a new one that includes a newer version of the firmware and received an error which mentioned a communication error with an encoder.  I tried contacting the manufacturer with no luck.

My question is if there is a place where the software is saved on the board, can I unsolder it and put it on the old board assuming that the IC where the program is stored is not damaged? Also, will unsoldering damage the IC or the stored firmware? Finally the IC where I suspect the program is saved is the one in the middle "LGIS" but I do not seem to find it anywhere.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: U10 looks like an eprom or flash chip. It is likely the firmware is in that chip. Can you show a part number for that device?

Comment: I agree with @Kartman that U10 is likely to be an eprom or flash chip. From the existing low resolution pictures U10 doesn't appear to have any markings. Not sure if that is due to the manufacturer deliberately obscuring the device marking, or due to what appears to some conformal coating used on other parts of the PCB. I.e. you may need to get the lighting / angle correct to take a higher resolution picture of U10 with a readable device marking.

Answer (score 3):

The picture of the PCB shows the obsolete Texas Instruments TMS320C32PCM40 DIGITAL SIGNAL PROCESSOR. The [datasheet](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/2548/TMS320C32.pdf) shows there is no user programmable internal non-volatile memory, so the program for the TMS320C32PCM40 will be stored in an external memory device. The datasheet shows an internal `BOOT ROM` which contains a *boot loader*:

> The TMS320C32 flexible boot loader loads programs from the serial port, EPROM, or other standard non-volatile memory device. The boot-loader functionality of the TMS320C32 is equivalent to that of the TMS320C31, and has added modes to handle the data-type sizes and memory widths supported by the external memory interface.

You would need to obtain the identities of the the other devices on the PCB to find which is the non-volatile memory device containing the program for the TMS320C32PCM40.

As for the LG DRIVE320V2 IC I also can't find any information on it, so is likely a custom device. It could be just a peripheral used by the TMS320C32PCM40, or may contain a program / configuration in internal non-volatile memory.

> Also, tried contacting the manufacturer with no luck.
>
> My question is if there is a place where the software is saved on the CB, can I unsolder it and put it on the old CB assuming that the IC where the program is saved is not damaged?

It may be possible to reverse engineer the PCB to identify the device which contains the firmware and move it between boards. However, without support from the manufacturer, and with the use of a LG DRIVE320V2 with no obvious publicly available datasheet it is difficult to say if moving the IC with the program will work.

The picture of the PCB shows a label with `V2.40/ST` which is presumably the revision of the PCB. If the two PCBs have a different revision, then potentially the program may not be be compatible between the two PCBs.

> The CB is used as control for a 375 kW drive

Given the high power of the drive, attempting modifications to the PCB without support from the manufacturer could have safety implications. The question doesn't mention:

1. What application the 375 kW drive is used for.
2. What functional safety requirements the drive needs to conform to.

Also @SteveSh mentioned in a comment that the non-volatile storage devices on the PCB most likely contain control loop parameters - that may be specific to the piece of hardware it's connected. I.e. swapping non-volatile storage devices between PCBs, but without running the original manufacturers calibration, could lead the worst case scenario of the 375 kW drive becoming unstable and causing damage to people or property.

Comment: Chester's comment about safety deserves some expansion.  The EEPROM/program most likely contains constants - control loop parameters - that may be specific to the piece of hardware it's connected to.  These constants determine the behavior of the system.  The wrong parameter could cause the system to not perform as expected or in a worse case become unstable.  This is not something you want to see happen with the kinds of power levels involved here.

Answer (score 1):

The TMS320C32PCM40 DSP will at least need some software to run. Although, it does not have built in storage memory so its firmware is stored somewhere else.

The LGIS part is likely some custom part that you won't find any information on very easily. So it is impossible to say anything about it. It may contain storage for the firmware, or it doesn't.
The firmware could also be spread out over more than one IC.

I'd go through all IC's on the board and look them up one by one, to try finding an EEPROM, flash or similar storage memory device. If there aren't any, I'd guess it's stored in the LGIS part.

> can I unsolder it and put it on the old CB assuming that the IC where the program is saved is not damaged?

That should be possible, assuming you do it with the correct soldering temperature etc. You can of course damage part if you don't do it right.
Although, don't take for granted that nothing other than the firmware differs between these boards. There may be other differences, noticeable or not.